# Google Places Autocomplete Dropdown Invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-api, google-places-api

In my site, I have a functional google places autocomplete, but it is invisible. I know that it works because if I type in "123 Main Street" and then move my arrow key down and hit enter- the address information will append to the inputs as normal.

I attempted adding this to my CSS:

```
.pac-container { z-index: 1051 !important; }
```

But it did not work.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was simple.

I just increased the z-index even more.

```
.pac-container { z-index: 9999 !important; }
```